# Counter-proof of orthogonality of random points in a higher-dimensional unit sphere

Tags: probability, probability-theory, random-variables, analytic-geometry, dimensional-analysis

I seek to provide a counter-proof against the following statement about the unit sphere in a N-dimensional space, with a large value for N.

**Statement**: *Two randomly selected points on the surface of the sphere are nearly orthogonal.*

**Counter-proof using a random arc length**

Create an arc of a unit circle with a length of random value in the interval of (0, π) and drop it on the surface of the N-dimensional sphere at a random place with a random orientation in the (N-1) dimensional surface. The two ends of the arc locate the two random points. However, the length of the arc does not have a high probability of being nearly π/2.

**Causes for the orthogonality found in theory and in computations**

I think the *pole and equator* method is only one of the multiple possible methods to estimate the probability in this case. Random selections in a multi-dimensional continuum might have indeterministic probabilities.

Question: What are the flaws in my reasoning?

Comment: The Jacobian for your process does not agree with what the world calls uniform distribution on the sphere.  If $x$ and $y$ are two random points you should be able to work out the expectation of $\|x-y\|^2$ for your way and for the usual way.

Comment: The mid points of the arc have a standard uniform distribution over the sphere's surface. The lengths and orientations have a standard uniform distribution. Any hints on why the end points would not have a uniform distribution?

Answer (score 1):

This is not a counterproof.

Implicit in the original statement ("two randomly selected points on the surface of the sphere are nearly orthogonal") is that the randomly selected points are (separately) chosen uniformly. The fact that the conclusion doesn't hold for some other distribution you propose just shows that your distribution (on pairs of points) isn't the uniform one.

This is, by the way, the same phenomenon illustrated by the [Bertrand Paradox](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Bertrand_paradox_(probability)). You might find it instructive to study that paradox, which is (at least dimensionally) simpler than the situation you describe.

Comment: Of course, my distribution is not the same as the one used by the original statement, but I don't think one can claim that one of these distributions is uniform and the other isn't. For example, the distribution used by the original statement isn't uniform as well, as it selects the random points one after the other, imposing an artificial order among the elements which is not related to the uniformity of the distribution.

Comment: And actually Bertrand Paradox supports my counter proof, as I have already stated, by indicating that there could be multiple ways of constructing randomness, leading to paradoxical truths.

Comment: The term uniform has a precise meaning, so one certainly can claim that one distribution is uniform and the other is not.

Comment: For any distribution on pairs of points we can define a new distribution simply by reversing the orders of the pairs of points. The ordering of the points isn't an issue for uniforming in the sense that if we apply this operation to the uniform distribution, we get the uniform distribution back.

Comment: In any case, I don't see where you've mentioned the Bertrand Paradox. It's true that there are "multiple ways of constructing randomness" in the sense that there's more than one distribution on the space of pairs of points on the $N$-sphere, but it's a little grandiose to describe this situation as "leading to paradoxical truths". What's going on here is just that (1) different distributions give different results, and (2) the particular result ("...nearly orthogonal") you mention implicitly refers to a particular distribution, nothing more.

Comment: Whether uniformity is an expected property of randomness is debatable, as it imposes an artificial pattern (uniformity). Randomness is a product of bounds of an interval, source definition and perception. Uniformity is relative to the metric space. There is no natural randomness or absolute uniformity. Once can't even create a random number in an unbounded interval.

Comment: Further, a point in a space is minimally defined in the context of another point (origin or center) in terms of distance between these two points and orientation of that distance. Thus, a pair of points is defined by coordinates for a single point.

Randomizing the distance and orientation between the pair of the points, in their space, is equivalent to defining a single random point.

Comment: My point is, accepting the orthogonality statement and its proof is equivalent of accepting one of the cases of Bertrand's paradox and dismissing others. Sorry, I stated about this paradox, in a related post at mathoverflow.

Comment: Your issue is semantic, not mathematical and whether "uniformity is an expected property" is irrelevant. Like I wrote above, the term "random" in the original statement implicitly refers to a particular probability distribution, and it's the one everyone (well, almost everyone) will understand it to refer to absent context indicating otherwise. Similarly, if someone speaks of a random point in a bounded interval, readers will assume that the distribution is uniform unless specified otherwise.

Comment: In any case, it's strange to object to the use of "random" without qualification as imprecise (despite that most readers will understand what is meant) but specify that objection in likewise imprecise language that don't have any common meaning ("uniformity as an expected property of randomness", "randomness is a product of bounds of an interval, source definition and perception", "there is no natural randomness or absolute uniformity", "a point in a space is minimally defined in the context of another point", etc.).

Comment: In case it's helpful, I would say that a point in a space is "minimally defined in the context of another point" if it makes _no_ reference to the "other point," and this is exactly what the uniform distribution does. Either way, as I wrote above, there's nothing particularly deep going on here, and I don't think continuing this exchange would be productive.